# I'm confused about this C++ constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I tried searching for an answer, but not sure exactly the best terms to use to describe this...

I am reading a book on SFML programming, and one of the examples has me confused with the usage of the constructor.

Lets say we have class A and class B. Class A has a member variable of type B (memberB). The constructor for A looks like:

```
A::A() : OtherMemberType(with, params), memberB()
{...}
```

Given that memberB is being initialized with the default constructor in the initialization list, what is the purpose of explicitly listing it in the list? Wouldn't the same effect be had without including it in the list?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. I have now learned the (basic) difference of value-initialization vs. default-initialization.

For more context, since the idea of "class B may be broken was brought up", here is the code example from the text [SFML Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849696845):

```
class Game
{
    public:Game();
        void             run();

    private:
        void             processEvents();
        void             update();
        void             render();

    private:
        sf::RenderWindow mWindow;
        sf::CircleShape  mPlayer;
};

Game::Game()
: mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application")
, mPlayer()
{
    mPlayer.setRadius(40.f);
    mPlayer.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    mPlayer.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
}
```

So with that context, does anyone know some of the specifics of SFML? Is sf::CircleShape "broken", or is this a redundant call to the default constructor?

Adam

Comment: The effect would be exactly the same. Welcome to the C++ world...

Comment: @doc: The effect would be exactly the same for some types, but with a difference that could cause undefined behaviour for other types. Welcome to the C++ world.

Comment: @MikeSeymour but as `memberB` is instance of `class B` then it's not a primitive type. C++ world.... :P

Comment: @doc: Even if it is a class type, there's still a difference if it doesn't declare a default constructor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `"Lets say we have class A and class B.  Class A has a member variable of type B..."`

Comment: @doc Please read Mike's answer and mine.

Comment: @doc: Sorry, I didn't notice that part. My edited comment still stands: there can still be a difference for class types.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Don't get me wrong. I dont wan't to neglect your useful comments and answer, but `"Given that memberB is being initialized with the default constructor...`"

Comment: @doc: Then whether there's a difference depends on whether that constructor is implicitly or explicitly defined.

Comment: @doc "Given that memberB is being initialized with the default constructor..." that is a statement that adds no information to the question. The question is whether it makes a difference to initialize the member in the initializer list or not. The answer is it can make a difference.

Comment: @juanchopanza I have assumed that `class B` is not an aggregate and provides a constructor. But if it's not a case then you are right.

Comment: `sf::CircleShape` class has defined default constructor, so there's no difference. http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1CircleShape.php#a06a5e136da1cfa3bd2a945a5c7f718d3

Comment: @doc well done, you've shown that _for this specific type_ there's no difference, but your comments above are still highly misleading in general.

Comment: @JonathanWakely sorry for that. For some reason my interpretation of mentioned sentence was that `class B` provides user defined default constructor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By including it in the initialiser list, the member is *value-initialised*. If it weren't, it would be *default-initialised*. Whether there's a difference depends on the type.

If it's a class type with a declared default constructor, then there's no difference: that constructor will be used in either case.

Otherwise, value-initialisation will zero-initialise primitive types (and primitive members of class types), while in some circumstances default-initialisation will leave them uninitialised, with an indeterminate value.

**UPDATE:** In your specific case, the class does have a [default constructor](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1CircleShape.php#a06a5e136da1cfa3bd2a945a5c7f718d3), so the explicit initialisation is redundant. But redundancy isn't necessarily a bad thing - it indicates that it's being deliberately value-initialised, not just forgotten about.

Comment: Curious: will it change the order things are initialized? Maybe it's included in the constructor initializer list to express the order in which things are initialized?

Comment: @tenfour: No, members are always initialised in declaration order.

Comment: So, suppose we have `struct B { int a }; struct C1 { B b; } c1; struct C2 { B b; C2() : b() {} } c2;` Do you claim, then, that `c2.b.a == 0`, while `c1.b.a` is indeterminate?

Comment: @KubaOber: Yes. (Although that depends on the storage duration of the variable. If it's static, then it's zero-initialised anyway).

Comment: Hmm. Nice to know, although I think that in practice it'd be very risky to depend on it. It's much safer, IMHO, to have `B() : a(0) {}`. It's too easy to forget the value initialization of an instance of `B` somewhere. Can you come up with any examples where this behavior is useful?

Comment: @KubaOber: Value-initialisation also applies to class types (if they don't have a user-declared default constructor), where `a(0)` wouldn't work.

Comment: That's true, but what I'm saying is that it's only proper to have a user-declared default constructor, than to have to remember that for a member to be properly initialized you have to explicitly value-initialize it. Basically, I consider *any* C++ class that requires such value initialization to  be broken and I'd fail it on a code review. Requiring value initialization breaks the class's encapsulation - it exposes an irrelevant implementation detail to the user, and penalizes the user for ignoring said detail.

Comment: @KubaOber It is not an entirely irrelevant detail: it gives you a choice of initialization. Maybe your application can't afford for the members to get zero-initialized. C++ gives you a lot of control, and with that comes some pain/potential for mishap.

Comment: @KubaOber it's useful for example with templates. Often you dont know the type of template argument `T`. Imagine that T can be `int` as well as `complex` number (where `complex` is an aggregate), which does not provide single argument constructor. You can initialize both of them with `T()`.

Comment: Sorry - I was trying to add more info than the comment box was going to let me. Chalk it up to a newbie mistake. I edited the original post instead - I hope that's the right way of doing it.

Comment: @doc Sure, but that's a specific case, then, and doesn't go against the expected behavior. Numeric types in C++ generally don't initialize themselves. I should have been clear that I was talking about explicit types not subject to the template parametrization. It's perfectly sensible to have `template <class T> struct S { T t; S() : t() {}; }` if it makes sense for `T` to be `complex` or a similar type. It makes zero sense to do `struct S { vector<int> v; S() : v() {}; };`

Comment: @KubaOber I stick to convention that `struct` keyword is reserved for aggregates. If it's not an aggregate then it's a `class` and it must have well defined behavior and perform initialization of its members by default. Dunno why C++ standard had not introduced such distinction for data structures defined with `class` keyword (to mark the difference between PODs defined with `struct`).

Comment: @doc That's an interesting idea. The whole struct-vs-class debacle seems very artificial. I always thought that the `class` keyword was superfluous.

Comment: @KubaOber I have to agree with that. I also think that coding conventions about `struct` and `class` just cause confusion (not enforced by the language, and slightly different everywhere) and even make people forget that they are really the same thing. `struct` was kept for C compatibility, `class` adopted most likely as an OO fad.

Answer (score 16):

Initializing the member in the initializer list [*value-initializes*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) it. Omitting it from the list [*default-initializes*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) it,

If `B` is a non-aggregate and has a default constructor, there is no difference.

If `B` is an aggregate, then there may be a difference. *default-initializing* it means if it contains built-ins these may not get initialized. *value-initializing* it would eventually have the effect of zero-initializing its members.

This is an example where the semantics of the initialization would be different:

```
struct B
{
  int i, j, k;
};

struct A
{
  A() : b() {} // value-initializes b: b.i, b.j, b.k zero initialized

  B b;
};

struct AA
{
  AA() {} // default-initializes b: b.i, b.j, b.k have no initialization

  B b;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Given what mike and juan have said, I'd say that class `B`'s implementation is broken iff it requires to be value-initialized like that *unless* it'd be reasonably expected to behave that way.

Generally, given a properly designed class - with a user-provided default constructor iff if has POD members - there should be no difference in behavior between value- and default-initializing the member of type B.

Some special classes may not perform zero-initialization of their members and they may lack a default constructor. `std::array` is one such class. They attempt to retain the performance of the raw type underlying their implementation. Members of such classes will require the value initialization.

There are several possibilities:

1. Class `B` is has the usual behavior the value initialization is superfluous. Specifically:

   a) class `B` has no POD-typed members, and the non-POD typed member types are all implemented in line with possibility #1, or

   b) class `B`'s user-written default constructor initializes all POD-typed members as appropriate.
2. Class `B` has the semantics of a performance-optimized type, such as a numerical type or a replacement for raw C arrays. It lacks a default constructor and won't initialize unless you perform value initialization. Example: `std::array<T>` where `T` is POD.
3. Class `B` is a template parameter. In absence of any constraints on `B`, the value initialization is the only safe choice. `B` could be `std::array`, after all.
4. Class `B` is broken. Its members will be properly initialized if its instances are value-initialized. It needs to be fixed.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the claim that any type which leaves members uninitialized is broken and needs to be fixed. There are plenty of types such as `std::array` which don't initialize all their sub-objects when default-initialized. Zero-initializing all elements of a large array takes up cycles which might be entirely redundant of the next thing you do is explicitly set every element to some other value anyway. It is a valid design for some types to leave data uninitialized by default and allow the user of the type to decide whether or not initialization is appropriate in a given situation.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That's true, but the semantics of such types are very clear about what they do and what they do not. In a vast majority of cases, the lack of a default constructor that performs appropriate zero-initialization of the members should be an optimization that is performed given results of benchmarks. You're making a tradeoff between safety and performance - you better had a good reason for that tradeoff. Your counterexample types are valid but are rather special. They shouldn't be the general design pattern.

Comment: OK, I've withdrawn my downvote after your edit, since it no longer just says all types either initialize all members or are broken, and admits the existence of other types :)

Comment: `std::complex` is a bad example. Its default constructor actually does initialize the members.

Comment: @T.C. So that only bolsters my point, then :) Such broken classes are not as frequent as it seems. Thanks!